# syntax to return a number of results per page

Tags: linq

I have this linq statement that returns result and i wanted to add the specifications of how many items are displayed per page. I know the default is 10 per page how can i change it to 40?

```
var _roster = DataCBase.StoredProcedures.GetUser<Users>(userID, r => new Users
        {
            Name = RosterColumnMap.Name(r),
            Email = RosterColumnMap.Email(r)
        });
```

**Get User**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetUser<T>(int userId, Func<IDataRecord, T> modelBinder, int resultsPerPage = 10, int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        if (userId < 1)
            throw new NullReferenceException("The sectionId cannot be null, when retreiving an element");

        if (resultsPerPage < 1)
            resultsPerPage = 1;     // enforce bare minimum result set

        if (pageNumber < 1)
            pageNumber = 1;         // enforce one-based page numbering

        SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetUser");
        _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "userId", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = userId });
        _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "resultsPerPage", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = resultsPerPage });
        _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "pageNumber", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = pageNumber });

        return DbInstance.ExecuteAs<T>(_command, modelBinder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Linq nor entity framework have any default number of records 'per page'. But since your `GetUser` function includes a `resultsPerPage` parameter, you can just do this:

```
var _roster = DataCBase.StoredProcedures.GetUser<Users>(userID, r => new Users
    {
        Name = RosterColumnMap.Name(r),
        Email = RosterColumnMap.Email(r)
    }, 40);
```

To limit the number of results in Linq use the the [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method:

```
var _roster = DataCBase.StoredProcedures.GetUser<Users>(userID, r => new Users
    {
        Name = RosterColumnMap.Name(r),
        Email = RosterColumnMap.Email(r)
    }).Take(40);
```

Comment: Added the `GetUsers` and found where the 10 is coming from. I want this changed because i will be using an infinite-scroll js to load data as the user scrolls down rather than dealing with pages or having all the info loaded and taking a long time.

Comment: @Amina I've updated my answer. Note that simply increasing the page size will not allow you to do infinite scrolling. That's a *lot* more complex, but assuming you're javascript is sound, this would reduce the number of queries to the database.

Comment: I am planning on using a plugin for that so we will see how that goes. But thanks for your help on this post.